# Disabling a filter for only a few paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, springfox

How do I get a filter to apply to every request off the root path except for ones I want to ignore? Here's my example:

I have a Spring Security filter like so:

```java
private static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), basicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
           .ignoring()
               .requestMatchers(SecurityServletRequestMatchers.servletIgnoreAuthMatcher());
    }
}
```

This filter populates a `CustomApiToken` object which contains all of our header information and puts it in the Spring Security context `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token)` for easy access to the token on the requesting controller.

I'm trying to add Springfox to the project, which means I want to disable the filter for the UI and API docs pages.

My original attempt was to add a clause to the method:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http
        .requestMatcher(SecurityServletRequestMatchers.servletIgnoreAuthMatcher())
        .headers() //.servletIgnoreAuthMatchers has all the swagger urls also
            .defaultsDisabled()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

However I discovered that this only takes the second clause into account due to Spring Security only accepting the last clause.

I've since tried:

```java
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/**")
        .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .requestMatcher(SecurityServletRequestMatchers.servletIgnoreAuthMatcher())
        .headers()
            .defaultsDisabled()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

But that left the web filter on the Springfox URL giving me a missing authentication token error.

I've tried looking around here, and on the internet, but none of the examples have given me an acceptable response yet.

Comment: since you have written a custom filter, you are on your own. Then you have to do all the exclusions by yourself. Spring has had support for Baerer tokens for 3 years now with filters that you can customize. No idea why you would write a custom security solution from scratch which is usually concidered bad practice https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture i suggest when you are looking around on the internet that you look at the reference first

Comment: @Toerktumlare As far as I understand, for what I'm trying to do using an authenticationfilter is a pretty common pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731231/authentication-with-custom-token-in-spring-boot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354138/spring-security-token-based-authentication. I see articles using this pattern well into 2020 so it doesn't seem so crazy to me. Granted, I'm not looking for my bearer token to be in my security context, I want other specific header values (like IAT) in my security context at the controller level; hence the filter.

Comment: My jwt token auth is being done at a higher level at the api gateway layer, with a completely separate application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your custom `AuthenticationFilter` you can define a `RequestMatcher` and use it before doing your logic, like so:

```java
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final RequestMatcher ignoredPaths = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui");

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
        if (this.ignoredPaths.matches(request)) { 
             filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
             return;
        }

        // do your logic
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `shouldNotFilter` method of `OncePerRequestFilter` in your custom filter to split your *filter* and *not_filter* logic, e.g. like this:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final List<AntPathRequestMatcher> excludedMatchers;

    public AuthenticationFilter (List<AntPathRequestMatcher> excludedMatchers) {
        this.excludedMatchers = excludedMatchers;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // your filter logic here
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return excludedMatchers.stream()
                .anyMatch(matcher -> matcher.matches(request));
    }
}
```

By default this method always returns `false`, so a filter is applied to any request unless otherwise specified.

Note, that `AntPathRequestMatcher`'s constructor also can take http method, allowing to create more specific *not_filter* logic, if you have multiple endpoints with the same path and different request methods, but want to allow a free access only to a specific one.