# How to apply a security filter only on a restricted http path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with my Spring security configuration. I just want to basically apply an authentication filter to some paths, and not to other path. But the filter i have defined is applied on all the HTTP request ever what i write in the configuration.
Here is my code.

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user")
      .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$DmzAlIznZz3faNQx1eBTBOw6fNiGE105fKoHkvskYTMXH5OFUE6iy")
      .roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
      .antMatcher("/admin/**")
      .authorizeRequests() //
      .anyRequest().authenticated() //
      .and()
      .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Override
  @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}
```

JWTFilter:

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


  @Autowired
  private JWTUtils jwtUtils;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException, ServletException, IOException {

    String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

    String token = null;
    String userName = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null) {
      userName = jwtUtils.extractUsername(token);
    }

    if (jwtUtils.validateToken(token)) {
    } else {
      httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
      return;
    }

    if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, null);
      usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
  }
}
```

For example if i try to call this servlet:

```
  @PostMapping("/login")
  public ResponseEntity<UserDetails> login(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    try {
      Authentication authenticate = authenticate(user.getName(), user.getPassword());
      UserDetails authenticatedUser = (UserDetails) authenticate.getPrincipal();

      return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(
          HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
          generateToken(authenticatedUser.getUsername())
        )
        .body(authenticatedUser);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }
  }
```

My filter is called to verify if the client is authenticated but it is my login end point so my client is accordingly not authenticated yet...

For me the code I found on internet that should resolve this problem is this one:

```
 @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
      .antMatcher("/admin/**")
      .authorizeRequests() //
      .anyRequest().authenticated() //
      .and()
      .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
```

You can find this code in the security config.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling a filter for only a few paths in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553077/disabling-a-filter-for-only-a-few-paths-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

To exclude urls for the security filter, you should override the other configure method that accepts a WebSecurity as an argument and specify the url paths to ignore...

eg.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/login/**");
}
```

Another option you could look into is to configure form based login in spring security...

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
      .and()
      ...
      .logout();
  }
```

It also looks like you're custom coding oauth2 authentication.  Have you looked at what spring security 5 provides out of the box for securing urls with jwt tokens?

Check out the documentation at
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try what you said

i am not familiare with Oauth2. What i want to implement, is just to add an authication system but i dont want to delegate to an Oauth server to authenticate my user. Is what the documentation is about?

Comment: Never of your two solutions seems to work... when i CURL my login servlet I always fall into the JWTFilter I have implemented