# How to secure specific URL with filter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-security

I want to secure only few specific endpoints and if any request comes to secured endpoint I want to apply filter on that.
This is what I have tried as of now:

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .addFilterAfter((Filter) MyFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/api/users").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

I am expecting that it should secure only **`/api/users`**  and if any request comes to this secured endpoint, then it should go through the filter. But right now each request is going through the filter.
Please suggest what is the right way to do this.

Comment: *I am expecting that it should secure only /api/users and if any request comes to this secured endpoint, then it should go through the filter.* This is wrong, the filter is always applied to all URLs in the filter chain. There are several ways to exclude one URL for the filter. The most one is to implement it in the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `RequestMatcher` in your Filter and make it only apply to requests that match.

```java
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

  private RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/users");

  @Override
  public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
      if (!this.requestMatcher.matches(request)) {
        // the request do not match, do nothing but continue the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
      }
      // do the filter logic
  }

}
```

Comment: In case I have to match multiple endpoints, then how we can handle it. I tested with one endpoint and it's working.

Comment: Your RequestMatcher implementation can be a OrRequestMatcher, and you can pass many AntMatcherRequestMatcher to that implementation

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Why didn't you vote to close as duplicate of your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553077/disabling-a-filter-for-only-a-few-paths-in-spring-security ?

Comment: Sorry, didn’t remember that answer