# PermitAll with addFilterAfter not working

Tags: spring-security

Struggling with new Spring Security 6.x. Having the following `SecuritsFilterChain`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    public SecurityConfiguration() {}

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/index.html**", "/swagger-ui/index.html/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class));

    return http.build();
}
```

Unfortunately the URL:

```
/swagger-ui/index.html
```

executes the filter `JWTAuthorizationFilter` which should not be executed.
Without the filter it works.

Comment: I've added an answer, but would you please clarify a few things, just in case the answer isn't quite what you need? 1. "leads me to the Filter" - which filter? I'm guessing you mean "leads me to JWTAuthorizationFilter" - please clarify either way, 2. "Without the filter it works" - which filter and what do you mean "it works"? 3. It might help for you to say what you expect to happen when `/swagger-ui/index.html` is requested.

Comment: @jzheaux 1. yes, i mean that filter i added in the addFilterAfter Method. 2. and 3. When i disable to add the filter and call the Uri `/swaggger-ui/index.html`, the page is displayed. Otherwise the uri match is forwarded to the filter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling a filter for only a few paths in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553077/disabling-a-filter-for-only-a-few-paths-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, allow me to suggest a few changes for readability, and then I'll comment after that:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers(...).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .addFilterAfter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)

    return http.build();
}
```

The nice thing about this is that it's a little easier to see the authorization rules separately from the rest of the filters being configured.

#### permitAll

Authentication filters are called on every request.

`permitAll()`, `authenticated()`, and `hasRole()` all work with `AuthorizationFilter`, which is [placed after the authentication filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-security-filters) in the filter chain.

What this means is that `JWTAuthorizationFilter`, `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, and all authentication filters are not affected by any authorization rules that you add.

If there are certain requests that `JWTAuthorizationFilter` should skip, that is up to that filter to say so.

Comment: ok thats understood. But it is not clear for me how can i avoid those uri matchers to be forwarded to the filter?

Comment: Why is it a problem? Servlet Filters by design run on every request, so your question seems to be fighting against the grain a bit. The URI matchers do not configure filter matching, they configure whether the downstream MVC controllers (for example) should be called. Each filter will be called on every request and it is up to that filter to decide whether to inspect the request or to pass it along to the rest of the filter chain.

Comment: Ok, that was a misunderstanding of mine how to work with requestMatchers. Now it is more clear that the filter is called for any request independent from the requestmatchers. The logic to filter a request or not should be done within the filter itself.