# Unable to bypass URLs in custom authentication OncePerRequest filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, spring-security

I am working on a custom authentication filter in my Spring Boot application and I'm trying to bypass certain URLs from being processed by the filter.
Based on the logging statements below, it is confirmed that the web access control expressions have been applied to the URLs to be bypassed.

```
[main][39mDEBUG[0;39m com.airbender.trv.config.security.userAuthenticationFilter     : Filter 'userAuthenticationFilter' configured for use
o.s.s.c.a.a.c.AuthenticationConfiguration$DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
2024-03-11 01:56:20,161 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/value/v1/service-history-pdf/**']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,164 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,165 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,165 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.png']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,165 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.gif']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,165 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.svg']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,165 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.jpg']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,166 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.html']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,166 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.css']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,167 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/**/*.js']
2024-03-11 01:56:20,167 [main][39mDEBUG[0;39m o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for Ant [pattern='/value/v1**']
```

Despite this configuration, when I attempt to access these bypassed URLs using Postman, the filter is still scanning them. I have tried various combinations and configurations, but It cannot working as expected.

**Configuration:**

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer sb = constuctAntMatcher();
//      http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(_MAX_AGE_IN_SEC);
         http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/value/v1/service-history-pdf/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()                   
                .antMatchers(sb.toString())
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

            // Add our custom JWT security filter
            http.addFilterBefore(userAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            return http.build();
    }
```

I have referred to many posts on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions worked for me. I am unable to figure out if I am making a mistake or if I need to configure the security in a different way than described above. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling a filter for only a few paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553077/disabling-a-filter-for-only-a-few-paths)